# Не получается отправить AJAX запрос к контроллеру

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Цель такова: отправить данные на сервер, использую AJAX хелпер

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PhotoSessionInfo", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "generalPhotoPos", LoadingElementId = "loading-spin" }))
  {
        <span>Название фотосессии (будет отображаться в галереи): </span>
        <br />

        @Html.TextBox("sessionName", null, new { @class = "sessionName" })
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>Выберите изображение, которое будет являться заставкой фотосессии:  </span>
        <br />
        <input type="file" name="generalPhoto" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>Выберите изображения: </span>
        <br />
        <input type="file" name="photos" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
        <button type="submit"> Отправить </button>


  }
            <div id="generalPhotoPos">
                <img src="~/Content/loading-spin.svg" id="loading-spin" />

            </div>
        </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

В контроллере мне нужно получить данные и передать их в модель, после чего использовать в частичном представлении:

```
private Models.ImgDataBaseEntities db = new Models.ImgDataBaseEntities();
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PhotoSessionInfo(HttpPostedFile generalPhoto, string sessionName, HttpPostedFile[] photos)
    {
        long generalPhotoSize = new System.IO.FileInfo(generalPhoto.ToString()).Length;
        string[] photoNames = new string[photos.Length];


        for (int photo = 0; photo<= photos.Length; photo++ )
        {
            //Если данные больше 2мб, то возвражается представление с сообщением об ошибке
            long size = new System.IO.FileInfo(photo.ToString()).Length;
            if (size > 2000000 && photos.Length ==0)
            {
                return PartialView("Error");
            }

             photoNames[photo] =  System.IO.Path.GetFileName(photos[photo].FileName);
        }

        string [] photoURLs = new string[photos.Length];
        for(int i =0; i<=photoNames.Length; i++)
        {
           //Сохраняю фотографии в папку на сервере, после чего записываю в массив путь к этой фотографии
          photos[i].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/Photos/"  + photoNames[i]));
            photoURLs[i] = "~/images/Photos/" + photoNames[i];
        }
        string generalPhotoURL = null;
        if (generalPhoto != null && generalPhotoSize > 2000000)
        {
            string generalPhotoName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(generalPhoto.FileName);
            generalPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/GeneralPhotos/" + generalPhotoName));
            generalPhotoURL = "~/images/GeneralPhotos/" + generalPhotoName;

        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("Error");
        }

        string imgURLs = null;

        for(int i = 0; i <= photoURLs.Length; i++)
        {
            imgURLs += photoURLs[i] + "," + " ";
        }

        Image image = new Image
        {
            Title = sessionName,
            ImgUrl = imgURLs,
            GeneralImgUrl = generalPhotoURL
        };

        db.Images.Add(image);

        return PartialView(image);
    }
```

Далее код класса модели:

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public string GeneralImgUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Код частичного представления (как и модели) тут бесполезен.

В чем проблема? Данные даже не приходят на контроллер.

Вот тег формы, который создает Ajax.BeginForm :

```
<form action="/Home/PhotoSessionInfo" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loading-spin" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#generalPhotoPos" id="form0" method="post">
```

Comment: Контроллер тот же самый?

Comment: Да, контроллер Home

Answer (score 0):

> Данные даже не приходят на контроллер.

-- как Вы это выяснили?

Давайте разберемся в том, что делает эта строчка:

```
long generalPhotoSize = new System.IO.FileInfo(generalPhoto.ToString()).Length;
```

Что же она, собственно, делает? Ошибку?

Comment: Я поставил точку останова на методе PhotoSessionInfo,так я выяснил, что никакие данные туда не приходят.   Эта строчка, как я понимаю, должна получать размер файла в байтах

Comment: "поставил точку останова на методе" - что это значит? В методе строк пятьдесят.

Comment: В начале метода

Comment: Вы разведчик? или партизан? Точку останова ставят на строке кода. На какой строке Вы ее поставили?

Comment: Первая строка метода

Comment: @LevKostychenko Очень хорошо. Что значит "данные не приходят в контроллер"?

Comment: Во-первых- программа не останавливается, во-вторых - при наведении курсора на переменные, которые принимает метод, они не имеют никакого значения. Извините, если я задаю «тупые» вопросы, да и отвечаю так же... Я только начинаю работать с mvc.

Comment: @LevKostychenko Если программа не останавливается, то "наведение курсора на переменные" - бессмысленно. Будем работать над формулировками. То есть Вы хотите сказать, что метод контроллера вообще не вызывается?

Comment: Да, не вызывается

Comment: @LevKostychenko Посмотрите в браузере, как выглядит тэг формы, созданный вызовом `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PhotoSessionInfo", ...` и добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил тег формы